# Intellij IDEA не отображает log файлы

Tags: файлы, intellij-idea, логирование, log4j

В структуре проекта Intellij IDEA не отображает файлы log.

Answer (score 1):

Для включения отображения log файлов:
File -> Settings -> File Types Находим там Log файлы. Поле Registered Patterns будет пустым для него. Нажимаем + и вписываем *.log
[image: Скрин settings - editor - file types]